# Dropdown for virtual product in frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, virtual-products

Is it possible to have dropdown list with different prices for a virtual product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can use the custom options:
[image: Custom options]

Result should look like this on the list page:

[image: list page result]

and like this on the product view page:
[image: view page result]